# HTTPERR folder filling up with thousands of Timer_ConnectionIdle entries (IIS 8.5)

Tags: api, http-headers, httpresponse, iis-8.5

I get about 500mb of these logs a day (granted my site is getting 90-120 million requests a day.) I had to make a scheduled task to purge these weekly so they don't fill up the servers SSD.

I finally wanted to take a stab to figure out what could be causing this, I have two theories/solutions. But wanted to know the pros and cons before attempting these, as I plan on testing them in production...

### Connection: Close ?

Currently set to Keep-Alive, but not sure if it's actually being utilized as this is a RESTful API. I have to assume SOME connections are taking advantage of this as I'm only getting a few hundered Timer_ConnectionIdle every 5 seconds and a lot more requests are coming in than that.

Is their an easy way to diagnose Keep-Alive is being utilized before turning it off?

### Response.End() ?

```
If (responseType = "JSON") Then
    Response.ContentType = "application/json"
    Response.Write(APIResponse)
End If
```

Once I return a JSON/XML response I'm not calling Response.End... Could this be the culprit?

Any suggestions or clarity would be greatly appreciated, I know they say if it's not broke, don't fix it... And my API is running great, with no connection limit errors to the users, just big logs... Thanks

Comment: check this out: http://serverfault.com/questions/202095/httperr-filling-up-fast-with-timer-connectionidle

Comment: @Avi Thanks, I know how to disable it, but I think that is possibly masking an underlying issue...